# Dynamically created script not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, echo

I am trying to dynamically create a script but it is not working.

I tried:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("hello!");</script>';
echo '<script>alert("hello!");</script>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">$( document ).ready(function() {alert("hello!");});</script>';
```

please help

Upon request here is the full code where the script is dynamically created at:
In fact , there is a php page that has a javascript file that calls an ajax function on press of a button that sends the type and calls this php page , this one will dynamically create the bootstrap carousel with the right pictures (give the right category)

```
<?php

//the login database info goes here too

    $_type= $_POST['Type'];
$_category= $_POST['Category'];



if($_type == "adult")
{
    $title = "FOR THE ADULTS";

}
else
    $title = "FOR THE KIDS";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT image,imagealt FROM gallery where type='".$_type."' AND category='".$_category."' ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$result1 =  $conn->query($sql);


?>


<tr>
    <td class="GalleryImageInfo">
        <div id="parent_back" >
          <h1>GALLERY</h1>
          <p class="ForAdults"> <?php echo $title ?>  </p>
          <p class="ButtonGalleryPreview" style="text-align:center"> <?php echo $_category ?> </p>


<?php

$countit = 0;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row

?>

<div id="slider_caption" > <div>

<?php
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $image_description = $row["imgdesc"];
     echo "
                        <div  class=\"carousel-caption caption-".$countit."\">
                            <h3>Description</h3>
                            <p>".$image_description."</p></div>";

                        $countit++;
    }

echo "</div></div>";


echo "<p  class=\"GalleryImageBack\" style=\"font-family:BandaBold; color:#6c555e; font-size:15px;\"><i class=\"fa fa-arrow-circle-left\" style=\"margin-right:10px; font-size:15px;\" ></i>BACK</p>
</div>
</td>


<td style=\"width:100%\">
<div class=\"container\" style=\"width:100% ; padding:0px !important;\">

  <div id=\"myCarousel2\" class=\"carousel slide\" data-ride=\"carousel\">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class=\"carousel-inner\">";


$firstitem = true;


    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        //echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";

        $image_url = $row["image"];
        $image_alt = $row["imagealt"];

        if($firstitem)
       { echo"<div class=\"item active\">
        <img src=\" $image_url \"
        alt=\".$image_alt.\" style=\"width:100%;\">
      </div>";
      $firstitem= false;
        }

        else
       echo"<div class=\"item\">
        <img src=\" $image_url \"
        alt=\".$image_alt.\" style=\"width:100%;\">
      </div>";

    }


    echo " </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class=\"left carousel-control\" href=\"#myCarousel2\" data-slide=\"prev\">
      <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\"></span>
      <span class=\"sr-only\">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class=\"right carousel-control\" href=\"#myCarousel2\" data-slide=\"next\">
      <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></span>
      <span class=\"sr-only\">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</td>

</tr>";



echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">$(document).ready(function() {
    alert(\"hello!\");
});</script>";

} 
 else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: and what does the above return? any console errors?

Comment: Is that the complete contents of the page you are rendering back to the user?  Are you returning the <html> and a head or body or anything?

Comment: If it is the whole content of your page, it won't work.

Comment: no there is a lot of code in my page and it doesn't return any error ..

Comment: No need for html or the rest of the tags, this should work anyway.... Provide the rest of the PHP code, please P.S. Third attempt will work just if you have jQuery, otherwise error should be thrown...

Comment: @sinisake done .

Comment: Is there a reason to echo the script to the page, when you could just close the php tag and add the script as static content?

Comment: View Source and check to see if it is actually being added to the page

Comment: yes , the script https://codepen.io/RetinaInc/pen/GJbpB needs to update the caption in the carousel (the caption is outside the carousel)  but since the carousel is dynamically created , the script is enable to catch it and do the logic

Comment: yes i checked , it is there

Comment: specialeventsleb.com/gallery.php

Comment: Your console is throwing an error because you are missing a quote: `"#myCarousel2`. Should work with added quote: `"#myCarousel2"`

Comment: But you don't need to echo the whole script.  Just close the php tags and add the script as static content, with the variables that can change in php tags.

Comment: How  can I add this script to the carousel when the carousel is dynamically created?
$("#myCarousel2").on('slide.bs.carousel', function(evt) {

    var step = $(evt.relatedTarget).index();

    $('#slider_captions .carousel-caption:not(#caption-'+step+')').fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $('#caption-'+step).fadeIn();
    });

 });

Comment: It seems you're getting a little confused. From the view of the back end, this is a dynamic carousel, yes -- but within the browser, you're not fetching data via, for example, AJAX. The page itself, once PHP has constructed it, is static. Is that a fair statement?

Answer (score 0):

check if you added the jquery script in this page or not.

Comment: it is added in this page